# ¿Cómo puedo cargar una pagina dentro de un div de forma dinámica, según un menú en html5 y php?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html5, bootstrap

Buen día, estoy intentando cargar una serie de paginas php en otra (que es la principal) según de click el usuario en el menú, el problema que encuentro es que no sé como cargar el contenido de la derecha que es donde necesito mostrar las paginas sin tener que recurrir a copiar y pegar varias veces mi pagina principal con los cambios, según de clic el usuario en una opción. he investigado, pero no se si hay una opción para cargar las parte de la pagina en la cual se pueda hacer por ejemplo. primero el header, después el menú de la izquierda y luego la pagina php que quiero mostrar a la derecha del menú.
¡AGRADEZCO A QUIEN ME RESPONDA!

**Esta es la distribución de la pagina principal en booststrap 4.**

[image: distribución pagina]

Comment: La pregunta mas bien queda como: deberias?, ten en cuenta que la incrustacion de paginas web dentro de otras no solo consume muchos mas recursos, si no que ademas si abusas de ello la pagina puede volverse extremadamente lenta, y el uso de los `<iframe>` actualmente se encuentra muy desaconsejado, te aconsejo que en ves de querer cargar `html` externo en tu `html` mejor uses PHP que te renderice ese `HTML` de manera dinamica sin usar un `iframe`

Comment: Debes usar PHP, para crear diversas vistas de las páginas que quieres cargar y hacer uso de `includes` para poder reutilizar vistas.

Comment: No entiendo bien, no estas utilizando plantillas? Ya que basicamente es eso, lo que dice @JhonMaldonado